# How to use findById() in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I have tried this code and it continuously gives me an error.

```
      @GetMapping("/findbyid/{id}")
      public Optional<UserDTO> getUserByID(@PathVariable Integer id){
       return userservices.finBYID(id);
      }




     @Override
     public Optional<UserDTO> finBYID(Integer id) {

    return userrepository.findById(id);
     }
```

The result is:

```json
  {
   "timestamp": "2019-04-28T04:53:00.225+0000",
   "status": 404,
   "error": "Not Found",
   "message": "No message available",
   "path": "/user/find/1"
   }
```

Comment: The path in the response doesn't match what you've set in the mapping. Please double check you're making a request to the right endpoint, then give a [mcve]. Note that a conventional RESTful API would look like `/users/{id}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to code the request URI should be '/**findbyid**/{id}' but it was'/**find**/1'.

Comment: The path that u tape don't match with `@GetMapping("/findbyid/{id}")`, first of all check if the user exist then the URI should be like **/findbyid/{id}**.